# How to import data into Snowflake from a Sybase database backup?

Tags: database, import, backup, sybase

I am working on a project to import data from a Sybase database backup.  From my review of Snowflake documentation I see no mention of how one might do this other than writing custom ETL to export data for each table into a supported structured data format (e.g. csv or xml) and then load that file into snowflake.

Is there a way to have Snowflake load schema and data directly from a database backup file?  Even if there is a way to do this for some other database vendor (other than Sybase) that might be helpful.

Comment: Sybase database backups aren't a readable file but often a compressed binary file only readable by a backup server. Also if full database encryption is used then the backup file is also fully encrypted as well. This is where they differ from some other databases where a 'backup' is more like a schema export in clear text.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it doesn't fully answer my question about Snowflake's ability (or non-ability as I suspect) to import data directly from a database backup generally, Sybase or not.